# Null Pointer Exception while using putExtra and getExtras

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use putExtra and getExtras to pass some information in an android game I'm writing (it's a score). When I'm passing it, I use this code in the one class to put in the information:

```
Intent winScreen = new Intent(context, WinScreen.class);
winScreen.putExtra("score", "123");
```

And when I'm getting it, I'm using:

```
Intent x=new Intent(this, GameCall.class);
Bundle ebundle = x.getExtras();
String score = (String) x.getExtras().getSerializable("score");
```

I'm just trying to test with a sample score right now, so I don't think setting the value correctly is the problem. That was the suggestion I saw elsewhere for why such a null pointer would occur. I know it understands "score" as an extra. So I am stumped as to where the information is being lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an `Intent` to start a new Activity, you must use `getIntent()` to get that specific instance of the intent. Using `Intent x=new Intent(this, GameCall.class);` won't work. Try the following code:

```
Intent x= this.getIntent(); //in the WinScreen activity
String score = (String) x.getStringExtra("score");
```

Comment: I deleted my answer.  I overlooked the fact that the OP was using a new `Intent` to try to retrieve the extras.  This should be the correct answer, and `getSerializable()` might work considering the `String` class implements that interface.  However, I'd much prefer using `getStringExtra("score")` as suggested.

Comment: Should I create a new intent, then? That intent actually calls the next level in the game. The idea of this piece of code is to store the score before that new GameCall.

Comment: All you need to retrieve your score that you added to the `Intent` as an extra is `String score = getIntent().getStringExtra("score");`.

Comment: As Glendon has said, you don't need to create a new `Intent`. When you first send your `Intent winScreen`, it will start the new Activity `WinScreen` and the intent will be associated with this Activity, and can be retrieved using `getIntent()`.

Answer (score -1):

Using `Intent.getExtras()` returns a `Bundle` that you previously added to the Intent with the `Intent. putExtras()` method. To simply add a String to the Intent, use `Intent.putExtra(String tag, String value)` and get it using `Intent.getStringExtra(String tag)`. I've made this mistake myself many times; it's not very user-friendly xD

Comment: I see this "fix" suggested all over the place, and I have no idea why.  The documentation for `getExtras()` clearly says that it "returns the map of all extras previously added with putExtra(), or null if none have been added."  Just because you didn't specifically add a `Bundle` does not mean that you cannot use `getExtras()` to retrieve one.

Comment: `getExtras()` gets the Bundle previously added via the `putExtras()` method. I suppose it would make sense to do it this way, but alas, it does not work. Just use `putExtra()` and `getStringExtra()` and your app will work fine. No need to make Intents any more complicated than they already are.

Comment: Yes, it will return a `Bundle` previously added with `putExtras()`; it will also return a `Bundle` of any extras you may have added with `putExtra()`.  If it doesn't for you then you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: If you're just using Intents to communicate between Activities in your own app, there really isn't a reason to need this feature. You know what data you'll be adding and what tag you'll be adding it with, so you don't need a map of all extras.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you about that in the OP's case.  I even suggested using `getStringExtra()` because it's more readable, but you're saying `getExtras()` won't work.  However, it works fine.